# Selenium как выполнить javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

С помощью `selenium` открываю сайт, там в `html` есть следующий блок кода

```
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-1" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>
```

Мне нужно убрать последнее свойство стиля, т.е, `resize: none`

Как я понял мне нужно выполнить некий `javascript` с помощью `driver.execute_script()`, но как конкретно мне это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне помогло данное решение

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response-1').setAttribute('style', 'width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px;');")
```